# Text NOT going to new line

Tags: css, ajax

Hi i have a messing system which gets messages from the database. the problem is the messages are keep going and do not go to a new line in the window. no matter if i set the width to whatever. my code is below

this code is in the while loop. geting results from database and displaying them using ajax.

```
<p id='message' > " . $row["message"]. "</p>
```

code displayed in this, using ajax

```
<div id = "load_results" ></div
```

This is the css

```
 #message {
          background-color: blue;
          width:200px;
          margin-right: 50px;

      }

      #load_results {
          height:400px;
          overflow-y: auto;
          width:250px;
          padding-left: 10px;

      }
```

it needs to have an overflow on the y axis because there is multiple scrollable elements lined up on the page. and has to have a set height and width.

Comment: Are there spaces in the text?  if not it won't wrap/break.

Comment: There are spaces because its a message. Is there still a way? @RonRoyston

Comment: Note that you can't have the same `id` for multiple elements. Make `message` and `load_results` into classes instead.

Comment: @MrLister Very true I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly calling the text to `wrap`?

```
 #message {
   background-color: blue;
   width: 200px;
   margin-right: 50px;
   white-space: wrap
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue. Using `white-space: pre-wrap;` instead of `white-space: wrap;` solved my problem.